# Array de objetos con la clase 'vector'

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++, visual-c++, c++98

Queria saber como se podía crear un array de objetos con la clase vector y también llamar el método constructor de cada objeto del vector(array).

Lo que tengo hecho hasta el momento es esto:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Objeto{
    public:
        int valor;
        Objeto(int valor_){
            valor = valor_;
        }
};

int main(){
    vector<Objeto> elementos;
    return 0;
}
```

**Pero no se como llamar el método constructor de cada elemento(objeto) del array**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Queria saber como se podía crear un array de objetos con la clase vector.

Ya lo tienes:

```
std::vector<Objeto> elementos;
```

> Y llamar el método constructor de cada objeto.

Ya lo haces.

---

Tienes 3 maneras de añadir elementos a tu `std::vector`, según la documentación de la clase, su [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) tiene 8 firmas, de las cuales son relevantes (para tu caso) el constructor por defecto:

```
std::vector();
```

Lo único que hace es crear un vector vacío, es el constructor que estás llamando en tu `main`:

```
int main(){
    vector<Objeto> elementos;
    return 0;
}
```

Una vez creado el vector, para añadirle elementos tienes como opciones:

- Copiar dentro del vector un elemento creado fuera del vector.
- Mover dentro del vector un elemento creado fuera del vector.
- Construir elementos dentro del vector.

#### Copiar.

Es la manera más sencilla, creas el objeto que quieres insertar en el vector y seguidamente lo [insertas al final del vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

```
std::vector<Objeto> elementos;
Objeto o;

elementos.push_back(o);
```

También podrías [insertarlo en una posición específica](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

```
std::vector<Objeto> elementos;
Objeto o;

elementos.insert(elementos.begin(), o); // Copiamos 'o' al principio
```

#### Mover.

Si el objeto a insertar fuese un valor temporal, éste sería movido al interior del vector:

```
std::vector<Objeto> elementos;

elementos.push_back(Objeto{}); // El objeto creado es temporal
elementos.push_back({});       // Podríamos obviar el nombre del tipo, pues ya es conocido.
```

También funciona con objetos temporales:

```
std::vector<Objeto> elementos;

elementos.insert(elementos.end(), Objeto{}); // El objeto es movido al final
elementos.insert(elementos.begin(), {});     // El objeto es movido al inicio
```

#### Construir.

Puedes dejar que el vector [construya los objetos internamente](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) en el lugar que les corresponda:

```
std::vector<Objeto> elementos;

elementos.emplace(elementos.end()); // El vector crea el objeto directamente en el final
```

Si tu `Objeto` no hubiera tenido un constructor por defecto, podrías haber pasado los parámetros del constructor a la función `std::vector::emplace`:

```
struct Objeto {
    Objeto(int){};
};

std::vector<Objeto> elementos;

// El vector crea el objeto directamente en el final con el valor '1'
// como parámetro del constructor.
elementos.emplace(elementos.end(), 1);
```

Si siempre queremos construir elementos en el final del vector, tenemos una [alternativa para ello](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```
struct Objeto {
    Objeto(int){};
};

std::vector<Objeto> elementos;

// El vector crea el objeto directamente en el final con el valor '1'
// como parámetro del constructor.
elementos.emplace_back(1);
```

#### ¿Dónde se llama al constructor?

En el caso de *Copiar* el constructor se llama en el lugar en que crees el objeto original, al insertar el elemento en el vector se llama al constructor de copia.

En el caso de *Mover* el constructor se llama en el lugar en que se crea el objeto original, al insertar el elemento se llama al constructor de movimiento.

En el caso de *Construir dentro* el constructor lo llama internamente el vector, no intervienen más constructores en el proceso.