# ¿Como puedo normalizar una tabla reemplazando los nombres de las peliculas por un id y eliminar lo demas innecesario de la tabla?

Tags: c++, csv, tablas

Tengo un codigo el cual me lee el archivo y me escribe lo mismo, como hago para que me lea todo pero a la hora de que me lo escriba me sustituya el nombre de la pelicula por un id como pelicula1, pelicula 2,etc..Tambien que me escriba solo unas cosas en especifico ya que estoy creando una tabla aparte.

Inserto los indices de las columnas que tengo en el archivo principal [image: En esta imagen tengo en el archivo csv os indices de las columnas]

En esta imagen es un poco de lo que tengo en la tabla principal lo cual quiero hacer mas pequeño para que sea mas ameno de leer

[image: En esta imagen es un poco de lo que tengo en la tabla principal lo cual quiero hacer mas pequeño para que sea mas ameno de leer]

Yo quiero que se escriba al final una tabal la cual quede como:

```
id         Title          Descripcion      Actores
Pelicula1  Guardianes...  A group of....  Chris Pratt, Vin Disel....
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

vector <string> split(string line, char delim) {
  vector<string> tokens;
  int end = 0;
  const char* ws = " \t\n\r\f\v";
  int L = line.size();
  while (end<L) {
    int start = end;
    end = line.find(delim,start);
    if (end<0) end = line.size();
    string token = line.substr(start,end++-start);
    token.erase(token.find_last_not_of(ws) + 1);
    tokens.push_back(token);
  }
  return tokens;
}

}
void readCSV(vector<vector<string> > &columns,
  string filename, char delim) {
  ifstream file(filename);
  if (file.is_open()) {
    string line;
    bool firstRow = true;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
      vector<string> values = split(line,delim);
      int variable = values.size();
      for (int i=0;i<variable;i++) {
        if (firstRow) {
          vector<string> column;
          columns.push_back(column);
        };
        columns[i].push_back(values[i]);
      }
      firstRow = false;
    }
    file.close();
  }
}

void writeCSV(vector<vector<string> > &columns,   
  string filename, char delim) {  
  ofstream file(filename);
  int n = columns[0].size();
  int m = columns.size();
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<m;j++) {
      file<<columns[j][i];
      if (j!=m-1)
       file<<delim;
    }
    file<<endl;
  }  
  file.close();
}  

int main() {  
  vector <vector<string> > columns;
  readCSV(columns, "dataC.csv",'\t');
  writeCSV(columns, "output1.csv",'\t');

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola y buenos días/tardes/noches. Podrías convertirlas en clases, así siempre podrías acceder a todos los datos de las películas, se quedaría de manera más resumida y bonita.
Por ejemplo:

```
class PELICULAS{
     private:

            //Strings con los nombres de las pelis
            string nombre;
            string descripcion;
            string actores;

     public:

           //Funciones para poder usar las clases y constructores de la clase

};
```

No te pongo el constructor y el resto de funciones porque es la primera vez que contesto  y me parece cancerígeno que dejen todo el código en una línea(que seguro que hay una manera pero no lo se).
Te dejo un link a un vídeo en el que te explican lo básico de clases:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbVHbfIVxs4

Tambien el enlace a cpluplus: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Luego para acceder de manera fácil a las clases guárdalas en un vector de clases.

```
std::vector<clase> elementos;
Objeto o;
elementos.push_back(o);
```

o tambien

```
elementos.insert(elementos.begin(), o);
```

Debes de usar esta libreria: `#include<vector>`

Por si tienes dudas te dejo otro enlace que lleva a una buena explicación sobre el vector de clases:

[Array de objetos con la clase 'vector'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173551/array-de-objetos-con-la-clase-vector)

Comment: en C++: `private` y `public` van en minúsculas y las clases terminan con punto y coma `;`

Comment: Y los nombres de las clases deben empezar con mayúsculas.

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez Eso no es obligatorio, es una convecion.